# How to stop beeping sound from pioneer mobile robot and start the robot without pressing a push button?

Tags: ros, pioneer-3dx, p2os, p2os-driver, pioneer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu 12.04 and fuerte

Pioneer P3-DX

Hi,

I have two simple questions about the settings on pioneer mobile robot

Question 1:

The pioneer robot is giving a beep when it does not recieve any command from the joy stick. It does not give a beep when it receives commands to move. Could any tell how to change these beep settings ?

Question 2:

I have to press a push button on the top of Motors to start the pioneer after reset. Is it possible to not press the push button and yet get the pioneer mobile robot to move ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/93811/how-to-stop-beeping-sound-from-pioneer-mobile-robot-and-start-the-robot-without-pressing-a-push-button-?/) by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1935 on 2013-10-23

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm assuming you are using p2os. Have a look at http://wiki.ros.org/p2os_driver?distro=groovy. Unfortunately, it's somewhat broken and inconclusive.

1. Are you talking about the startup beep? If so, it may be possible to turn it off by launching with pulse=1.0. Don't know about any other beeps, unfortunately.
2. What I used to do is launch a script which would publish once on the /cmd_motor_state topic. So you'd do `rostopic pub /cmd_motor_state p2os_driver/MotorState 1` (1, if I remember correctly, means 'enable' - too bad the documentation doesn't actually say what the values are expected to be)

---

Originally posted by [autonomy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3784/autonomy/) with karma: 435 on 2013-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2013-10-28**:
Thanks!,
For the second point, it it possible to have a command in launch file?

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2015-04-07**:
I made an p2os_enableMotor node which publishes to `/cmd_motor_state` which I run in the launch file.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By the way, there is a list of beep sounds made by the Pioneer at http://robots.mobilerobots.com/wiki/Robot_Beeps  You may be hearing the motion watchdog that stops the robot and beeps if there is a comminications timeout , no data received from software, i.e. the p2os_driver node.  It could happen if p2os_driver stopped sending commands to the robot (there is a no-op "pulse" command 0 that can be used), or if it hung, crashed or exited without closing the connection.

By default, motion is disabled, but most software enables them after setup and its ready to control the robot.  I'm not sure if p2os_driver does this, I think rosaria does.

It is also possible to configure the controller firmware to disable all sounds if you want.

---

Originally posted by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) with karma: 821 on 2015-04-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1